# C++ DLL not generating Library, but is looking for Library. error LNK1104

Tags: c++, dll, visual-studio-2013, dllexport

I am working on a small project right now that will use two DLLs. One of them is working fine, but my other one is not. I was previously getting a LNK2019 but that was solved by adding in the references. I am now getting a LNK1104 error:

```
Error   1   error LNK1104: cannot open file '...System\TechGeniusOutSourcePayRoll\Debug\Classes.lib'
```

Obviously going through the relevant folder, there is no 'Classes.lib' but I have got code to allow for an export, similar to the first DLL. Below is the code for my working DLL

```
//MathFunctionsDLL.h
#ifdef MATHFUNCSDLL_EXPORTS
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#else
#define MATHFUNCSDLL_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#endif

namespace MathFuncs {

    class MyMathFunctions {
public:
    //Return Supervisor Total Salaries
    static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double add(double a, double b, double c);

    //Return Salaried Total Salaries
    static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f);

    //Return Contracted Total Wages
    static MATHFUNCSDLL_API double add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e);
    };
}

//MathFunctionsDLL.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "MathFunctionsDLL.h"

using namespace std;

namespace MathFuncs {
    double MyMathFunctions::add(double a, double b, double c) {
        return a + b + c;
    }

double MyMathFunctions::add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f) {
    return a + b + c + d + e + f;
    }

double MyMathFunctions::add(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e) {
    return a + b + c + d + e;
    }
}
```

All this above is working fine. Below is the code for my second DLL.

```
//Classes.h
#ifdef CLASSESDLL_EXPORTS
#define CLASSESDLL_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define CLASSESDLL_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace Classes {

class employeeClass {
    string f_initial;
    string s_name;
public:
    void set_name(string fInitial, string sName);
    string get_f_initial();
    string get_s_name();
    };

class supervisorClass : public employeeClass{
    double salary;
public:
    void set_salary(double sal);
    double get_salary();
    };

class salariedClass : public employeeClass{
    double salary;
public:
    void set_salary(double salary);
    double get_salary();
    };

class contractedClass : public employeeClass{
    double hourlyRate;
    double hoursWorked;
public:
    void set_hourlyRate(double rate);
    void set_hoursWorked(double worked);
    double get_hourlyRate();
    double get_hoursWorked();
    };
}

//Classes.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "Classes.h"

using namespace std;

namespace Classes {

void employeeClass::set_name(string fInitial, string sName) {
    f_initial = fInitial;
    s_name = sName;
    }

string employeeClass::get_f_initial() {
    return f_initial;
    }

string employeeClass::get_s_name() {
    return s_name;
    }

void supervisorClass::set_salary(double sal) {
    salary = sal;
    }

double supervisorClass::get_salary() {
    return salary;
    }

void salariedClass::set_salary(double sal) {
    salary = sal;
    }

double salariedClass::get_salary() {
    return salary;
    }

void contractedClass::set_hourlyRate(double rate) {
    hourlyRate = rate;
    }

void contractedClass::set_hoursWorked(double worked) {
    hoursWorked = worked;
    }

double contractedClass::get_hourlyRate() {
    return hourlyRate;
    }

double contractedClass::get_hoursWorked() {
    return hoursWorked;
        }
}
```

I would be grateful for any help offered as to why the library is not being generated. As a side note, this is my first time dealing with Class Libraries and i'm not too comfortable with Module Definition Files. Thank you again.

Comment: You seem to have not used CLASSESDLL_API in any of the function declarations unlike using MATHFUNCSDLL_API in other header file. Also you haven't define CLASSESDLL_EXPORTS in the cpp to enable export.

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a simple fault. Thank you again.

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it make the comment as one?

Comment: Hum... Second DLL: would you like to export whole classes or just functions?

Comment: The whole classes preferably